# Function to Apply Factor Levels & Labels to Numerous Columns at Once

Tags: r

I have a survey dataset that I imported as an SAS file but it did not include the text labels that are associated with the numeric codes in the dataset.

I'm trying to apply the factor function to all variables and then have the respective levels and labels for each variable.

I have a main dataframe with the actual data, and then a second dataframe with the text labels corresponding to each value for each variable.

So, for example, the variable column names in the main dataset are A1, B1, C1, D1. The second dataframe with the labels is listed below with dummy text. And for each variable, there are varying numbers of values that need text labels.

```
labels_list <- structure(list(VariableName = c("A1", "A1", "A1", "B1", "B1", 
"B1", "B1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "C1", "D1", "D1", "D1", "D1", 
"D1", "D1"), Value = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), Label = c("Red", "Blue", "Yellow", 
"Up", "Down", "Left", "Right", "Boston", "Atlanta", "Dallas", 
"New York", "Los Angeles", "John", "Jim", "Jake", "Bill", "Bob", 
"Brian")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -18L))
```

I'm trying to write a function to automatically label all the factor variables. The function reduces down the data to make sure that they each contain the exact same variables and then are in the exact same order. I split the table above into a list using the split function, and then each variable name above has it's own list, but I'm encountering an error when I try to subset the list in the for loop.

Below is the for loop I have written.

df = main dataset

labels_list = list with the value and text labels

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)) {
        for(j in labels_list) {
          if(names(x[,i]) == names(ahs_split[[j]])) {
            x[,i] <- factor(x[,i], levels = c(ahs_split[[j]][[2]]), labels = c(ahs_split[[j]][[3]]))
```

As I mentioned, my ultimate goal is to take this dataframe with the text labels and corresponding values for each variable and apply it to each one individually using the factor function. I've tried for almost a month now and am just very stuck so I could use any help. I'm not sure if anyone could possibly recommend a better approach or point me in the right direction. I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: You can use this page to paste you data an generate a table for stackoverflow: 

https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Answer (score 1):

One way is to convert your `labels_list` into a list of lists:

```
library(dplyr) # just using dplyr for the pipe %>%, otherwise everything is in base R

# Convert df to list of key:value pairs
labels_list <- labels_list %>%
  split(f = labels_list$VariableName) %>%
  lapply(function(x) list(key = x$Value, value = x$Label))
```

e.g.:

```
$A1
$A1$key
[1] 1 2 3

$A1$value
[1] "Red"    "Blue"   "Yellow"
```

This can be mapped onto your `df` col-wise with `apply`. This is a bit hacky as I put the column name as the first item of the vector passed to the function.

```
# Map labels onto sample data with factor()
apply(rbind(names(df), df),
  2,
  function(x) factor(x[2:length(x)],
                     levels = labels_list[[x[1]]]$key,
                     labels = labels_list[[x[1]]]$value)) %>%
  as.data.frame()

       A1    B1          C1    D1
1    Blue    Up      Dallas  Jake
2     Red  Down    New York  Jake
3  Yellow  Left      Boston   Jim
4  Yellow Right      Boston  John
5  Yellow  Down Los Angeles  Jake
6     Red  Left     Atlanta  Jake
7    Blue  Down    New York  John
8     Red  Down     Atlanta Brian
9    Blue    Up    New York   Jim
10 Yellow  Down     Atlanta  Bill
```

#### Sample Data

```
set.seed(1724)
df <- data.frame(A1 = floor(runif(10, 1, 4)),
                  B1 = floor(runif(10, 1, 5)),
                  C1 = floor(runif(10, 1, 6)),
                  D1 = floor(runif(10, 1, 7)))
```

Comment: yeah, definitely more concise than my solution

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I was able to get the labels_list with a $key and $value list for each variable. I just have the following questions about your final code:

-Why is there an rbind in the apply? What purpose is that service?

-How do I reference the labels_list in the function part of apply?

-What purpose is 'tmp' serving within the apply call?

Comment: My bad, `tmp` was an error, I had it in my working but forgot to update it for the final answer - it is meant to be `labels_list`. The answer has been updated. the `rbind` is there to make column names accessible to the `factor` function as the key for `labels_list`, there might be a better way to do this, but I don't know it.

Comment: Thanks so much Paul! I really appreciate your help. I'm so close to figuring this out but still no quite there.

When I run the apply code you provide I get a data frame with all  NAs. I've tried to write a function and use that in apply but that's to no avail.

What I'm struggling with most is how to iterate over each item in the labels_list.  I wrote the function to apply over 'df' but it tells me invalid subscript type 'list'

relabel_2 <- function(x) {
  for(i in ahs_split_label){
    factor(x[1:length(x)], levels = ahs_split_label[i]$value, labels = ahs_split_label[i]$key)
  }
}

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind some `tidyverse` verbs, you can reshape your data with `tidyr::gather`. Once it's in a long shape, you can join the data with the code lookup by variable name, and reshape it back into a wide format. This workflow scales for however many columns you need.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

labels_list <- structure(list(Variable = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("A1", 
"B1", "C1", "D1"), class = "factor"), Value = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L), Label = structure(c(15L, 
3L, 18L, 17L, 8L, 12L, 16L, 5L, 1L, 7L, 14L, 13L, 11L, 10L, 9L, 
2L, 4L, 6L), .Label = c("Atlanta", "Bill", "Blue", "Bob", "Boston", 
"Brian", "Dallas", "Down", "Jake", "Jim", "John", "Left", "Los_Angeles", 
"New_York", "Red", "Right", "Up", "Yellow"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-18L))

df <- tibble(A1 = rep(1:3,2),
            B1 = c(1:4, 1, 2),
            C1 = c(1:5, 1),
            D1 = 1:6
            )
```

A row number iterated over `Variable` will be necessary to spread the data, but you can drop it after it's no longer needed.

```r
df %>%
  gather(key = Variable, value = Value) %>%
  left_join(labels_list, by = c("Variable", "Value")) %>%
  select(-Value) %>%
  group_by(Variable) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  spread(key = Variable, value = Label)
#> Warning: Column `Variable` joining character vector and factor, coercing
#> into character vector
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>     row A1     B1    C1          D1   
#>   <int> <fct>  <fct> <fct>       <fct>
#> 1     1 Red    Up    Boston      John 
#> 2     2 Blue   Down  Atlanta     Jim  
#> 3     3 Yellow Left  Dallas      Jake 
#> 4     4 Red    Right New_York    Bill 
#> 5     5 Blue   Up    Los_Angeles Bob  
#> 6     6 Yellow Down  Boston      Brian
```

Comment: brilliant! Much easier

Comment: That was a very good suggestion. It had crossed my mind but for some reason I ruled it out. Thanks so much, Camille.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated @camille 's answer to use `pivot_longer()` instead of `gather()` and `pivot_wider()` instead of `spread()`, respectively, as the lifecycle of these two functions is superseded:

```r
# Labelling the values in multiple columns:
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = everything(),
               names_to = "Variable", 
               values_to = "Value") %>%
  left_join(labels_list, by = c("Variable", "Value")) %>%
  select(-Value) %>%
  group_by(Variable) %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Variable, 
              values_from = Label) %>%
  select(-row)
```